# Converting daily .csv data in R to aggregate weekly data using R

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I'm very new to R so I'm sorry if some of the terminology I use is incorrect. I have a large .csv file for daily visits, with the columns including the date (in D/M/Y format) and the number of visits that day in a seperate column. The date starts on 05/01/20 and ends on 06/11/20. I've plotted a daily time series of this data, and now I'm trying to plot a weekly time series, with the total sum of daily visits totaled together to get a weekly total, starting Monday and ending Sunday. I have looked through other similar questions on this site, and came across this code:

```
Week <- as.Date(cut(DF$Date, "week"))

aggregate(Frequency ~ Week, DF, sum)
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work. I would prefer to keep it as simple as possible. I also have the forecast package and zoo package installed if that helps.

Comment: *"I can't seem to get it to work"* doesn't really help us know what is going wrong. Are there error or warning messages? What do they say? Have you tried each step, e.g., does `cut(DF$Date, "week")` seem to work? Does `as.Date(cut(DF$Date, "week"))` seem to work? If you need more help than that, please post a small reproducible example - `dput(DF[1:10, ])` is a nice copy/pasteable way to share the first 10 rows of your data, including all class and structure info -- choose a different small subset if the first 10 rows don't illustrate the problem well.

Comment: None of it seems to work. I keep getting the error 'Error in cut.default(df$date, "week") : 'x' must be numeric' and 'Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Frequency' not found'

Comment: Well, that's super useful! That means `cut()` doesn't work, so everything after/outside the `cut()` command doesn't have a chance. The error makes it sound like your `Date` column isn't the right class.... what class is it? (If you post a reproducible example with `dput()` as I mention in my first comment, we'll be able to see the class for ourselves...)

Comment: I don't think I'm able to share the data. However, I looked using the str() function (if this is correct?) and it says the date is classed as 'chr' and the visits is classed as 'int'.

Comment: Great - so you need to convert it to `Date` class **before** you `cut()` it - not after as in your code. If it's in `D/M/Y` format this should work `DF$Date = as.Date(DF$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Simple fix, but seems to work now! Thank you!